# Starting ExIrc supervisor fails

Tags: elixir, irc

I'm tinkering with ExIrc to make a simple bot, but i can't make it work.

I'm getting this Error:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application streamingutils: TwitchSniper.start(:normal,
 []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: TwitchSniper.Bot
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (ArgumentError) argument error
            :erlang.apply([%TwitchSniper.Bot.State{client: nil, handlers: [], host: "irc.chat.twitch.tv", name: "Paul Schoenfelder", nick: "hajtosek", pass: "my password", port: 6667, user: "hajtosek"}], :host, [])
            (streamingutils) TwitchSniper.Bot.init/1
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:239: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I was trying to use ExIrc library: https://github.com/bitwalker/exirc

I just copied most of the code from the readme, just swapped data

Code:

```
defmodule State do
    defstruct host: "irc.chat.twitch.tv",
              port: 6667,
              pass: "password",
              nick: "hajtosek",
              user: "hajtosek",
              name: "Paul Schoenfelder",
              client: nil,
              handlers: []
end

def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [%State{}])
end

def init(state) do
    # Start the client and handler processes, the ExIrc supervisor is automatically started when your app runs
    {:ok, client}  = ExIrc.start_client!()
    #{:ok, handler} = ExampleHandler.start_link(nil)

    # Register the event handler with ExIrc
    ExIrc.Client.add_handler client, self

    # Connect and logon to a server, join a channel and send a simple message
    ExIrc.Client.connect!   client, state.host, state.port
    ExIrc.Client.logon      client, state.pass, state.nick, state.user, state.name
    ExIrc.Client.join       client, "#channel"
    ExIrc.Client.msg        client, :privmsg, "#channel", "Hello world!"
    ExIrc.Client.msg        client, :ctcp, "#channel", "Hello world!"

    IO.inspect "IRC activated"

    {:ok, %{state | :client => client, :handlers => [self]}}
end

def terminate(_, state) do
    # Quit the channel and close the underlying client connection when the process is terminating
    ExIrc.Client.quit state.client, "Goodbye, cruel world."
    ExIrc.Client.stop! state.client
    :ok
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a typo in the README. The `state` argument to init is always a list (it receives the list given to `GenServer.start_link`). So the issue is that you are attempting to use state like a struct when it isn't one. Just change the function head for `init` to `[state]` instead of `state` and you'll be good to go.

EDIT: Also worth noting that you should take a look in the examples folder on GitHub for full applications which use exirc, they are more realistic examples.

Comment: Thank you very much, gotta report to the author of the lib.

Comment: I am the author of the lib, so consider it reported ;)